# From where does nucleophile attack the ketone in a nucleophilic addition reaction ?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I inserted a picture to help show where my misunderstanding lies. 
I know that in the nucleophilic addition of ketones and aldehydes , a racemix mixture is produced . And I know that the reason is that the molecule can be attacked by the nucleophile from “either side of the molecule” or “above and below”
But I can’t seem to picture that .
In the picture I added , I show the one place/direction of attack that makes sense to me , could someone please show me the other “side” ? 
[image]

Comment: Draw in 3D or build a model of  the enantiomers of the cyanohydrin to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to an animation of cyanohydrin formation. You have to click on the reaction arrow and the individual step will play. http://www.chemtube3d.com/Nucleophilic%20substitution%20at%20the%20carbonyl%20group%20-%20Cyanohydrin%20formation.html

Since the carbonyl is completely planar, the nucleophile could either approach from the front or the back. While your diagram seems to indicate the nucleophile attacks in the same plane as the carbonyl (180° angle from O–C–nuc), in reality the angle of approach is roughly 107° (Bürgi–Dunitz angle).